# Simple Flowcharts

Tags: c, flowchart

```
void main()
{
    int numTickets;
    float discount;
    float total = 0.0;
    int numKids = 0;
    float ticketPrice = 19.00;
    printf("Enter number of tickets: ");
    scanf("%d", &numTickets);
 if (numTickets > 10)
 {
   discount = 0.15;
 }
 else
 {
   discount = 0.0;
 }
   printf("Enter number of children: ");
   scanf("%d", &numKids);
   total = numKids*ticketPrice/2.0 + (numTickets – numKids)*ticketPrice;
   total = total*(1.0 – discount);
   printf("Total = %.2f \n", total);
}
```

basically, im helping my cousin study and one of the questions is to draw a flowchart for that. the problem is iv forgotten everything i ever knew about flowcharts! Is there a standard for the variable declerations at the top? I can make up the rest of it actually, just not sure how to start em anymore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular assignments (like your variable initialisations) should appear in a normal rectangle (like those in http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d6/FlowchartExample.png).

Remember that IO (like your `printf`/`scanf` statements) should be in parallelograms, and conditional branches in diamonds.

Comment: In that picture it only mentions the variables M and F when they are being assigned values, so i see that i could put total = 0.0 in a rectangle, but what about something like discount which is being declared but not yet used? does that get left out until its used? or delcared at the same time?

Comment: @confusified, it's purely a matter of convention. You can leave it out (what is most common, since a flowchart is high-level, you don't need these implementation details) or include it (if it's important to emphasise it's point of declaration). If no convention has been defined, I suggest you include it, it can't hurt. The rectangle is for all in-memory actions, which includes variable declarations.

Comment: Thanks for that, Whenever i'v needed a flowchart nobody else has needed to see it so i do it whatever way works for me, but considering as this is for my cousins exam, i thought i should find out if there was a convention he should be following.

Comment: @confusified, a pleasure. As to convention, I suggest your cousin ask his/her teacher what is expected of them, since really it's a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score 1):

The very basic rules:

- variable declarations (and in general blocks of code) go into rectangular boxes
- conditions (also of iterations) go into diamonds
- outputs go into parallelograms

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) article can be useful.

Comment: Im mainly wondering about the decleration of variables that arent being initialized yet, eg declaring something like int i; as opposed to int i = 3;

Comment: as davin already pointed out there aren't such detailed rules for flowcharts, since they are conceived to contain high level informations